# Are the .Values and .Keys in a ImmutableSortedDictionary guaranteed to be sorted?

Tags: c#

In C#, are the .Values and .Keys in a ImmutableSortedDictionary guaranteed to be sorted, please?

The following code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<long, string>
        {
            {3, "Three"},
            {1, "One"},
            {2, "Two"}
        }.ToImmutableSortedDictionary();

        foreach (var p in dict)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{p.Key} - {p.Value}");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var k in dict.Keys)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(k);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var v in dict.Values)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
```

Behaves as I was expecting, it prints all in order. Are there any guarantees that it will always do so? I checked online documentation and it does not say anything one way or the other.

Thank you.

EDIT: Neither https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesorteddictionary-2.keys?view=netcore-3.1 nor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesorteddictionary-2.values?view=netcore-3.1 say one way or the other, from what I understand, the documentation only guarantees that a .GetEnumerator() on the dictionary will be sorted. So it seems that the first loop in the code above will always be sorted, but I am not sure about the second and third.

Comment: Yes based on the type of the key.  String numbers will sort "1","10","100", "2","20","200"  while numbers will sort 1,2,10,20,100,200.

Comment: I think it's not documented properly.  
The `Keys` and `Values` properties are only documented to implement their respective properties of the `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>` interface - which is specifically documented as unspecified order - "The order of the values in the enumerable collection is unspecified" - but classes implementing both properties must guarantee the same order is used in the `Keys` and `Values` properties.

Comment: The docs are feeble, implicit assumption is that you'd work from [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, the docs for SortedDictionary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.keys?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_SortedDictionary_2_Keys do state that Keys are ordered. I am tempted to think it is an oversight on ImmutableDictionary docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when document is not clear, [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Immutable/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableSortedDictionary_2.cs) talks (as @404 pointed out).

## Conclusion

I agree with @mjwills. Since current documents (.NET Core 3.1) do **not** specify what the order of returned objects is, we **cannot** safely assume anything.

[Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesorteddictionary-2.keys?view=netcore-3.1):

> Gets the keys in the immutable sorted dictionary.

[Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesorteddictionary-2.values?view=netcore-3.1):

> Gets the values in the immutable sorted dictionary.

---

### **Warning**

Method behaviors below are based on *current implementation (.NET Core 3.1)* of [ImmutableSortedDictionary](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Immutable/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableSortedDictionary_2.cs). **Those behaviors are subject to change, please see conclusion aforementioned.**

- `Keys` will return sorted results
- `Values` will **not** return sorted results

That is easy to verify by running OP's code. The result for `Values` is not sorted.

```
One
Two
Three
```

**Reason**

Both `Keys` and `Values` are the result of enumeration of [Node](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Immutable/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableSortedDictionary_2.Node.cs) which implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the keys.
/// </summary>
internal IEnumerable<TKey> Keys
{
    get { return Linq.Enumerable.Select(this, p => p.Key); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the values.
/// </summary>
internal IEnumerable<TValue> Values
{
    get { return Linq.Enumerable.Select(this, p => p.Value); }
}
```

`Node` is an implementation of AVL tree, which adds/removes `Node` always based on key (*not value*) comparison `IComparer<TKey> keyComparer`. That is why `Keys` are always sorted, while `Values` are **not sorted by itself**.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds the specified key. Callers are expected to have validated arguments.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key.</param>
/// <param name="value">The value.</param>
/// <param name="keyComparer">The key comparer.</param>
/// <param name="valueComparer">The value comparer.</param>
/// <param name="overwriteExistingValue">if <c>true</c>, an existing key=value pair will be overwritten with the new one.</param>
/// <param name="replacedExistingValue">Receives a value indicating whether an existing value was replaced.</param>
/// <param name="mutated">Receives a value indicating whether this node tree has mutated because of this operation.</param>
/// <returns>The new AVL tree.</returns>
private Node SetOrAdd(TKey key, TValue value, IComparer<TKey> keyComparer, IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer, bool overwriteExistingValue, out bool replacedExistingValue, out bool mutated)

/// <summary>
/// Removes the specified key. Callers are expected to validate arguments.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key.</param>
/// <param name="keyComparer">The key comparer.</param>
/// <param name="mutated">Receives a value indicating whether this node tree has mutated because of this operation.</param>
/// <returns>The new AVL tree.</returns>
private Node RemoveRecursive(TKey key, IComparer<TKey> keyComparer, out bool mutated)
```

Comment: Thank you, in the current implementation Values are sorted by key, which is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly it just uses a linq `Select` statement to get an Enumerator for the Keys and Values as found in the [implementation source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Immutable/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableSortedDictionary_2.Node.cs,8cb65053ced0d597). So that would garantuee all 3 statements to be sorted as one also would expect from its class name.

Comment: `So that would garantuee all 3 statements to be sorted as one also would expect from its class name.` That is _not_ a guarantee. That is an implementation detail.

Comment: @mjwills but based on the information from the docs in the OP that garantuees a sorted dictionary for the `GetEnumerator` on the base class this would be no different?

Comment: Your logic doesn't follow. The contract doesn't _guarantee_ it uses a `Select` statement. So it doesn't _guarantee_ they will be in order. Now, it _makes sense_ for it to work that way - yes. But that is not the same as a _guarantee / contract._ Nothing stops the implementation from changing in future.